# Execute a js function with a cpp object as argument in v8

Tags: c++, v8

Is it possible to execute a js function with a cpp object as argument in v8?

if yes then how?

Lets say there is a function in javascript to traverse a Node tree .

```
function traverse_tree(root)    /* root is type of Node */
{
    no_of_node++;   /* no_of_node is a global variable in js */
    for(var i=0;i<root.children.length;i++)
    {
        traverse_tree(root.children[i]);
    }
}
```

and the Node tree is created in C++;

```
class Node
{
    public:
        std::vector<Node*> children;
}
```

how can I pass the root of the tree structure created in cpp in the function calling argument?

Answer (score 0):

### Short Answer

No, it won't be possible for you to access the actual C++ object from javascript.

- Webkit bridge works by making methods of a C++ object available in javascript under a particular name.
- Simple variables such as strings or integers can be passed as parameters to these function calls.
- Passing more complex objects is possible as long as they are HashMaps (key-value pairs).

This means that it's not possible to pass a reference so that the javascript and C++ "share" the object.

### Possible Implementations

1. You could create a method in your C++ application (either as a separate class or as part of Node) and expose that object to javascript. Then any implementation you require (such as searching for a particular item) can be done in C++. In this manner you've created a javascript API to your C++ applications functionality.
2. If you really need to do the processing in javascript then you'd have to figure out a way to convert your tree into some kind of HashMap (so that it's meaningful as a JSON object) and then return it as a parameter to javascript.